# how to count a detected face without recounting in opencv

Tags: python, detection, counting, opencv

I have made a system that can detect multiple faces that are looking at a screen,right now I have live video feed that can detect the faces with the box around the face, however those faces need to be counted. I need to be able to count every box/face that shows up without the program recounting a person.

I am relatively new to opencv, so I have no clue on how to go about counting these boxes/ faces without recounting.

Comment: You could use a hash table to keep track of "unique" face contours. The idea is to have the contour as the key of the hash table. The value doesnt matter since we just use the table to check if the contour is in the table by utilizing the property that hash tables can only have unique keys. So like this, `table = {}`, `if contour not in table:`, `table[contour] = 1`. To get the number of boxes/face contours, you can just check the size of the table

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i think as a start i would like to first know how to count the faces first.

Comment: You mentioned that you already can detect the bounding box for each face, so you can just simply iterate through each face contour

Comment: ok so i figured out how to count how many faces there are however because because this is live video detection it will count that same face with every frame this is where i need a system that can detect if  a face has been counted already.

Comment: @nathancy i am struggling to understand how a hash table can recognize if a face has been counted yet? because a face changes all the time so the program will recognize that the hash dose not exist and count the face after the face has been counted and added to the table because the say expression changed. or maybe im missing something

Comment: We use the property of a hash table in that keys have to be unique. So once you add the contour to the table as a key, this contour will be "unique" so say in the next frame you detect the same face contour again, if the contour is already in the table then the face has already been counted. If the contour is not in the table, the face is a new face so we add it to the table. You could also add another identifier to ensure that a face is unique

Comment: so i have added a system that will crop the face out of the frame, so how will i go about turning that image into a hash table?

Comment: Since you have the crop coordinates, this is simply a contour. You can use the contour as the key in the table

Comment: sorry i haven't come back to you in a while, so i have added a contour detector and was able to print out what i believe would be the values that would be used in this hash table, however my main concern still stands , if we are comparing these contour values, that would mean that every time a factual expression is changed there will be new contour values  that will not match that of the original face, so my concern is how do we actually go about comparing these contour values...